# Comparing two JavaScript Arrays that contain multiple value pairs

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have two arrays I'm trying to compare with data in the below format:

```
var order = [[1,"121"], [2,"111"], [2,"321"], [3,"232"], [3,"213"], [4,"211"]],
userBuilt = [[4,"111"], [1,"131"], [3,"321"], [3,"232"], [3,"211"], [3,"213"], [1, "X1X"]];

var exactMatches=[];
var incorrect=[];
```

I want to push the pairs that contain matching strings to one array called exactMatches=[] and items that are completely unique from the userBuilt array such as [1, "X1X"] and [1,"131"] to another array named incorrect=[].   The below code works for pushing the matches, but I cannot figure out how to push the unique pairs to the incorrect=[] array.

```
for ( var i = 0; i < order.length; i++ ) {
   for ( var e = 0; e < userBuilt.length; e++ ) {
      if(order[i][1] === userBuilt[e][1] ){
         exactMatches.push( userBuilt[i] ); 
      } 
   }
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Would you consider `[3,"321"]` in your example to be completely unique or only "partially unique" - going in neither result array?

Comment: @Bergi, that would only be partially unique.  [3, "321"] would get pushed to exactMatches.  Basically, if the string portions are in order and userBuilt, then they would get pushed to exactMatches.  If not, then they would go to the incorrect array.

Comment: Not sure why I got a down vote, it was a legitimate question, but it's cool I was able to get my functionality working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We don't know if a particular element has a match until the cross looping is entirely completed. So keeping track of indexes for non-matches and nullifying the index from the tracking array if later discovered.

We can immediately push the matches into an array when found.

```
var order = [[1,"121"], [2,"111"], [2,"321"], [3,"232"], [3,"213"], [4,"211"]],
    userBuilt = [[4,"111"], [1,"131"], [3,"321"], [3,"232"], [3,"211"], [3,"213"], [1, "X1X"]]

var exactMatches=[]
var incorrect=[] // keeping track of indexes so need two tracking arrays
    incorrect['o'] = []
    incorrect['u'] = []

for ( var i = 0; i < order.length; i++ ) {
    for ( var e = 0; e < userBuilt.length; e++ ) {
        if ( order[i][1] === userBuilt[e][1] ) { // comparing second element only
            exactMatches.push( userBuilt[e] );
            incorrect['o'][i] = null; // remove from "no match" list
            incorrect['u'][e] = null; // remove from "no match" list
        }
        else { // add to "no match" list
            if ( incorrect['o'][i] !== null ) { incorrect['o'][i] = i; }
            if ( incorrect['u'][e] !== null ) { incorrect['u'][e] = e; }
        }
    }
}
console.log(incorrect)
console.log(exactMatches)
```

`exactMatches` contains the matches.

```
[[4, "111"], [3, "231"], [3, "232"], [3, "213"], [3, "211"]]
```

`incorrect` contains the *indexes* of the elements that don't match.

```
[0, null, null, null, null, null] // order array
[null, 1, null, null, null, null, 6] // userBuilt array
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BloodyKnuckles/j30fm68z/1/)

In your example you're only comparing the string portion of the subarrays. The first number is disregarded. If you want an exact match of both elements, then simply include `order[i][0] === userBuilt[e][0]` in the condition.

Comment: thanks for the answer!  I didn't think to take this approach by tracking the indexes for non-matches.  I was able to get the functionality working as needed.  Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

```
for ( var i = 0; i < order.length; i++ ) {
for ( var e = 0; e < userBuilt.length; e++ ) {
    if(order[i][1] === userBuilt[e][1] ){
        exactMatches.push( userBuilt[i] );  
    } else {
        incorrect.push(userBuilt[i]);
    }
}
}
```

if it doesn't go in exactMatches, then it goes in incorrect, it seems, so just add the else statement that puts in in the incorrect array

Comment: What if there's a match later in the loop?

Comment: I tried doing the above, but unfortunately it wasn't working.  bloodyKnuckles answer below really helped me out.